# Django: django-import-export, change file name

Tags: python, django

I would like to request assistance in this matter

I am using [django-import-export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) to export my data to excel and I would like to change the export file name.

I tried to search but no related solution came up.

So, is it possible to change the file name? If so, where? Or at least some way to say that this file came from a readable source(I am naming my model like this: rep, appdata, etc. so if I export the info it wouldn't be comprehensible by the users(is it bad?))

Tried `verbose_name = u'your-fancy-class-name'` but the file name I exported is still named by the model class itself (appdata, rep, etc.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you write code to do export or is there an admin interface?

Comment: There is an admin interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following using Django Admin:

## admin.py

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin

class MyModelAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    # ...
    #Your configs and code
    def get_export_filename(self, file_format):
        filename = "%s.%s" % ("your_custom_filename",
                             file_format.get_extension())
        return filename
```

The original code is in Import-Export source code, specifically in /import_export/admin.py in class ExportMixin. Since ImportExportActionModelAdmin inherits this class, we are basically overwriting the method.

Answer (score 1):

in your admin.py :

```
def get_export_filename(self, request, queryset, file_format):
    filename = "%s.%s" % ("Réalisations de vente",
                          file_format.get_extension())
    return filename
```